# EF Core / Docker Compose: Table not showing new migrations after table deletion and restoration

Tags: c#, .net-core, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, dbeaver

I did a beginner mistake and deleted a table. I had to research how to recover it and was successful in doing so. But now my migrations are not working for that table. It just stays as the initial migration but the `ApplicationDBContextModelSnapshot` has the information I need to migrate to that table.

I have tried doing the `update-database` command to the specific migration and it says it's successful but no changes were made to that table. Same with doing a small change to the entity so I can execute an `add-migration`. The builds were successful but no changes were made.

I guess what I'm hoping for is syncing the Model Snapshot to my database and update that recovered table to the current state.

Comment: Is this a db running in a docker container, and api also? Please provide some more info

Comment: @axtck yes the db is running on a docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by removing the docker volumes then ran the update database command.
Everything is synced now.